# High Frequency Pulse Rate Generator - Science Fair

Tags: frequency, generator, pulse

( For our High School Science Fair) I am trying to find a pulse rate generator capable of producing 2.5Hz - 20,000 Hz utilize with over 10,000 LEDs all at once with several milliseconds in between pulses. Any ideas? Aside from the generator, how could I accomplish this?

We are doing an experiment on photobiomodulation (affecting cells with light). Living cells respond to and have different frequencies ( ex Brain Freq range 72 MHz). Living cells also respond to different wavelengths of light (ex 660nm).

Our group is utilizing something similar to a tanning bed, outfitted with specific wavelength LEDs. We are attempting to control pulse rate. We want to be able to set different pulse rates at 2.5Hz to 20,000Hz for 20 minutes.
Our goal is to see if there is an added affect to the cells on top of the light response by adding the same pulse rate as it is accustomed to.

Typically in Photobiomodulation, they will pulse lasers to prevent over-heating of the tissues. I asked for a pulse generator because a paper discussed that the same could be applied to LEDs.

We are trying to find ways to be able to program this (the ability to pulse frequency) into our light bed. We want to have an LCD screen that controls different programs that would change frequency of the 660nm + 850nm LEDs to preset programs or customized options. What components would you suggest. Can this be done?

Sorry to be vague I am 16 and this is for our science fair.

Comment: You could start by explaining how you intend to control the pulse frequency, rate and gaps between pulses. What accuracy and resolution (two different things!) do you require on these various parameters, and how often do they need to change? As it stands, this is far too vague to answer.

Comment: What does "utilize with over 10,000 LEDs all at one" mean and how do you expect to get several ms between pulses at 20 kHz pulse rate?

Comment: @Jimmythebull:  If you'd preface your replies to comments with an address ping such as I've applied to yours, then your replies would appear as items to be dealt with  in your targets'  inboxes and not require a separate  random trip back here just to see what , if anything, you had in mind.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, We are doing an experiment on photobiomodulation. Living cells respond to and have different frequencies. They have also respond to different wavelengths of light. Our group is utilizing something similar to a tanning bed, outfitted with specific wavelength LEDs. We are attempting to control pulse rate. We want to be able to set a pulse rate for 20 minutes. Sorry to be vague I am 16 and this is for our science fair.

Comment: @The Photon, We are doing an experiment on photobiomodulation. Living cells respond to and have different frequencies. They have also respond to different wavelengths of light. Our group is utilizing something similar to a tanning bed, outfitted with specific wavelength LEDs. We are attempting to control pulse rate. We want to be able to set a pulse rate for 20 minutes

Comment: @Jimmythebull, please edit your post to make your question clear. New readers shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking. Also, consider making your requirements clear to people who understand electronics but don't know anything about photobiomodulaition. What you've said so far does nothing to clarify for me what you are trying to solve.

Comment: timers rarely work well spanning 4 decades, 2 to 3 maybe consider a variable one shot and a CD4060 20kHz clock with binary output clocks to drive the one shot (74HC123) for fixed period and input clock cycle down ms, s , minutes and more,

Comment: Also FYI information like these frequencies are totally bogus and proven by MRI scanners and much other research to be totally bogus.  try another subject http://justalist.blogspot.ca/2008/03/vibrational-frequency-list.html

Comment: @Tony Stewart. Interesting that you should say that. I have been in contact with Prof Michael Hamblin, PhD at Harvard who felt that it hasn't completely been disproved that light at frequency can affect cells. Tiina Karu, one of the world's experts mentions the frequency of cells in her heavily cited paper on photobiomodulation.

Comment: and if they  haven't done a Network Analysis on tissue up to 6GHz as I have to measure absorption and return loss, I would say any dielectric can be excited with energy, but chemistry works very slow in comparison with the exception of ionization which is not so frequency selective. the iron in our bodies is not so magnetic to respond as in electrical circuits, and if one of those who hates microwave cooking,, understand that regular ovens operation a frequency 1000x higher in the IR band, which is closer to,the molecular and viral wavelengths of modern medicine. not xx MHz

Comment: I have also known and still practice the healing of damaged tissue with FIR or far IR and have a lamp that produces this as does almost every Dr. of acupuncture.. search Mineral Therapy Lamps . I bought mine in SFO from Dr Lee in mid80's and still use it when needed before My planned visit to a computer trade show.

Comment: Do you really want to buy more than 10,000 LEDs? Powering each of them with 2 V and 20 mA would require a 400 W power supply. 2 V and 100 mA would need 2000 W.